# Unable to make 'many-to-many' relation between Person and Address class

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, associations, hibernate-mapping

How do I make `many-to-many` relation between 2 classes **`Person`** and **`Address`** ? Following is the *POJO* for `Person` and `Address` respectively.

*Person :*

```
public class Person {
    private int personID;
    private String name;
    private Person person;
    private List addressList;

    public List getAddressList() {
        return addressList;
    }

    public void setAddressList(List addressList) {
        this.addressList = addressList;
    }

    public int getPersonID() {
        return personID;
    }

    public void setPersonID(int personID) {
        this.personID = personID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

}
```

*Address :*

```
public class Address {
    private int addressID;
    private String address;
    private Person person;

    public int getAddressID() {
        return addressID;
    }

    public void setAddressID(int addressID) {
        this.addressID = addressID;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

}
```

The relation I am trying to define is `A person can have many addresses and one address can belong to many people`.
I am unable to represent this in the `mapping xml`. This is what I have been able to do till now.

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
      <class name="pojo.Person" table="person">
          <id name="personID" column="p_id">
              <generator class="increment" />
          </id>
          <property name="name" column="p_name" />
          <list name="addressList" table="address">
              <key column="a_id" />
              <!-- DEFINE MANY TO MANY --!>
          </list> 
      </class>

      <class name="pojo.Address" table="address">
          <id name="addressID" column="a_id">
              <generator class="" />
          </id>
          <property name="address" />
      </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

How do I define `many to many` relation between these two classes ?

Comment: You need to add `private List<Person> persons` or `Set<Person>` in `Address` TYPE instead of Person person. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-join-m2m

Comment: @AVD How do I define `many to many` relation inside the `Person` class tag ? May be you can explain this in an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `private List persons` instead of `private Person person` in `Address` class.

Configure your mapping.xml like this

```
//For person.hbm.xml
<list name="addresses" inverse="false" table="person_address">
    <key>
        <column name="Person_ID" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <many-to-many entity-name="domains.Address">
            <column name="listAddress_ID" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-many>
</list>
//For address.hbm.xml
<list name="persons" inverse="false" table="person_address">
        <key>
            <column name="listAddress_ID" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="domains.Person">
            <column name="Person_ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
</list>
```

Comment: What does the `column` tag inside the `many to many` tag mean ? What is its essence ?

Comment: It is foreign key column of generated table.